# need to validate a date field with DOB field in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

Please help me!!
Need to validate a date field with Date Of Birth field while updating a form or at field level using angular js

Answer (score 0):

> ng-pattern='datePattern' will help you, check out below.

**View**

```
     <form name='dateForm'>
        Enter DOB : <input type='text' ng-model='theDate' name='theDate' ng-pattern='datePattern' required />
        <br>
        <input type='button' ng-click='validation(theForm)' value='Try to validate me !' />
        <br /> {{errorMsg}}
     </form>
```

**Controller**

```
     $scope.datePattern=/^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/i;
     $scope.errorMsg='';
     $scope.validation=function(dateForm){
      if(dateForm.theDate.$error.pattern)
        $scope.errorMsg='Not valid date';
      else
        $scope.errorMsg='Valid date !';   
     }
```

Comment: Could you help me in writing  code to compare a datebankrupt field which accepts date with DOB field  but should not be less than Date Of Birth field .